# Plot figures on the y axis with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, includegraphics

I have a graph and I want to plot on the Y axis figures instead of numbers or text.

My code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
[ 
xbar, xmin=0, xmax=10, 
width=7cm, height=8cm, enlarge y limits=0.5, 
xlabel={Closeness to the base firm}, 
symbolic y coords={
    \includegraphics[scale=0.022]{Logo/intellogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/HPlogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/nvidialogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.035]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.055]{Logo/googlelogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{Logo/microsoftlogo4.png}
    },
ytick=data, 
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}] 
\addplot[xbar,fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135}] coordinates {
(10, \includegraphics[scale=0.022]{Logo/intellogo.png})
(9, \includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/HPlogo.png})
(8, \includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/nvidialogo.png})
(7, \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png})
(6, \includegraphics[scale=0.035]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png})
(5, \includegraphics[scale=0.055]{Logo/googlelogo.png})
(4, \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{Logo/microsoftlogo4.png})
}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have all the logos displayed on the Y axis in the order of the y value mentioned in the `\addplot {}` section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. I removed the enlarge y limits. Apparently, it was making it overlay on top of each other.

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
[ 
xbar, xmin=0, xmax=8,
width=7cm, height=10cm,
xlabel={Closeness to the base firm}, 
symbolic y coords={
    \includegraphics[scale=0.022]{Logo/intellogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/HPlogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/nvidialogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.03]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.035]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.055]{Logo/googlelogo.png},
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{Logo/microsoftlogo4.png}
    },
ytick=data, 
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}] 
\addplot[xbar,fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135}] coordinates 
{
(8,\includegraphics[scale=0.022]{Logo/intellogo.png})
(7,\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/HPlogo.png})
(6,\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{Logo/nvidialogo.png})
(5,\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{Logo/broadcomlogo.png})
(4,\includegraphics[scale=0.035]{Logo/texasinstrumentslogo.png})
(3,\includegraphics[scale=0.055]{Logo/googlelogo.png})
(2,\includegraphics[scale=0.14]{Logo/microsoftlogo4.png})
}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now it looks properly:
[image]